# How to build an smtp server?

Tags: c#, .net, email, smtp

I'm interested in writing a SMTP mail server that just sends emails? I would be writing this in C# as a stand alone application. So if anyone can point me in the right direction or explain how an SMTP actualy sends out emails that would be great.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Read up on [RFC821](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc821) and and [RFC1870](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1870).  Your best bet as an introduction would be to look at examples of SMTP traffic.  Download [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/download.html) or use any other packet capture software, send some e-mails over SMTP, and study what was captured.  SMTP is a text-based protocol and fairly straight forward.

Please obey the RFCs with your application.  There are *so many* broken SMTP and other mail-related applications out there that make things difficult.  You might be better off just using the [SmtpClient Class built into .NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpclient.aspx).  At least, that's what I would use.  No sense in re-inventing the wheel, yes?

Comment: Thanks for some good ideas and yes it would be re-inventing the wheel but it would definatly be interesting as it seems email isn't something that seems to be clearly defined for a Simple Mail Transfer Protocol.

Answer (score 2):

In this open source project, there is everything you need including a windows services that does exactly what you describe:

http://mailsystem.codeplex.com

Comment: Will it allow me to send bulk/unlimited emails per day?